# RESTful API and separate web application acting as client; do i have validate the token received during login on every page load?

Tags: rest, authentication, client

I am aware that on every GET, POST, PUT, DELETE made by the client (separate web application) should provide the token back to the server as part of authentication.

My question is when a user logs in he gets back a token, but do i also have to send that token on every page load? for instance in a protected html page

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your api is trully restful, then yes, you will have to validate the token on each request. The reason is simple: there is no prior state to relate to, hence the stateless nature of restful APIs.

Comment: Appreciated answer! It generates another question: what would the resource look like for that? eg. a POST to /rest/session/:token and a response with either 200 or 401?

Comment: @MichalisDaniilakis I don't understand your question. Can you rephrase/elaborate?

Comment: Say for instance on every page load client is not allowed to see an html page, would i have to do a request before loading the page to the API like: this is my token, can i proceed?

Comment: @MichalisDaniilakis What do html pages have to do with restful APIs? I'm not sure I follow you.

Comment: The HTML page is just the interface that someone sees. In that page there are going to be some ajax calls to the API to retrieve resources that are going to be displayed on the page. But who tells me that page itself is protected? So my initial question was do i have validate the token received during login on every page load?

Comment: @MichalisDaniilakis You are mixing two different things here: web sites and web apis. The web api is a standalone application, as the website also should be. Of course, they can interact, in a sense that the website is consuming web apis. You can even provide identity service for your web site through the api.

Comment: @MichalisDaniilakis You can have your api issue tokens which can be used for authentication in your website. But the authorization should be entirely up to the website, based on the identity obtained from the token, of course.

Comment: Thanks! I appreciate your comments.

Comment: @MichalisDaniilakis So in this scenario, your website will surely be stateful, like all websites are. So no need to revalidate the token on each page load. Unless it changes, of course.

Comment: Exactly what i have in mind. But where do i store the token?

Comment: @MichalisDaniilakis Where related to what? The requests? The website?

Comment: @MichalisDaniilakis In the request you can store it as a custom header, like X-Auth-Token

Comment: The website. As a cookie for instance?

Comment: @MichalisDaniilakis In the website you can just use the session. Most likely it uses a session cookie already so no need to over complicate yourself.